# How can I create my own copy-protected DVDs?

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning, copy-protection

I'm giving out a collection of PDFs to some people on DVD, so I'd like to burn them so that they can't make copies (or at least not too easily).

Are there any applications or guides that will help me achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If each person you give the DVD to has unique data, then you can track illicit copies should they appear.  If you let them know this via a notice on the first .PDF, it can deter copying.

You can look into watermarking your .PDF's, or altering each .PDF somehow in a unique manner that ensures each individual has unique data and that you can trace that unique data back to a user.  One relatively simple way is to insert a random text or hex string somewhere in each .PDF and cryptographically sign it.  Keep the resultant `.sig` files as a record.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how well these work.

But [CDShield](http://mindestworx.free.fr/) and [CrypKey](http://www.crypkey.com/) are supposed to be popular, but not cheap.

Beyond encryption, there isnt much you can do to prevent them copying the files.  If they can read the files they can save them to their PC.

Answer (score 0):

You need specialty encryption software along with special burning hardware to effect CD/DVD copy protection:

- [How to copy protect a CD or DVD](http://www.cd-writer.com/cd_dvd_copy_protection.html)

It's expensive. I suggest you insert copyright notices into your PDFs and call it a day.

(And, not to put too fine a point on it, but PDF actually stands for "*Portable* Document Format." If you want to distribute ebooks, try using a format you can put DRM on.)