# copy protection and scheduled destruction of external devices

Tags: file-shredding

I want to share a video with my friends, I want it to be exclusive to him and for a limited period of time. Devices which I use can be pendrive, hardrive or dvd. I don't mind loosing the device altogether. I prefer software for this purpose. I don't know any programming languages.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks! ;)  Now, what's your specific question?  What have you tried already, what are you getting stuck on?  What makes you think they won't just make a copy of it while they have it (before timeout)?

Comment: Possible dupe: [How can I create my own copy-protected DVDs?](http://superuser.com/questions/327236/how-can-i-create-my-own-copy-protected-dvds)

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this have popped up before.  The short answer is if the data is viewable, then it *can* be copied.  Even if there was a program that encrypted the video so that it could not be copied directly as a file, the end user can always use video capture software to capture the video.